# If $X$ is a convex (closed) set and if $\text{int}\,X_i=\text{int}\,X$ and $\text{cl}\,X_i=\text{cl}\,X$ then is $\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$ convex?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, topological-vector-spaces, convex-geometry

Let be $V$ a vector topological space and so let be $X$ a convex (**closed**) set so that we suppose that $\mathfrak X:=\{X_i\subseteq X:\,i\in I\}$ a collection of convex subsets of $X$ such that
$$
\operatorname{int}X_i=\operatorname{int} X\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\operatorname{cl}X_i=\operatorname{cl}X
$$
for each $i\in I$. So with this hypotheses is the set $\bigcup\mathfrak X$ convex? **In particular if the statement is generally false is true when $X$ is closed?** Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Perhaps look for a counterexample in two dimensions and two subsets $X_1, X_2$.

Comment: @GEdgar I just proved but unfortunately it seem I was not able, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a triangle in the plane.  $X$ is the triangle together with its interior.  $X$ is a closed convex set.  Let $X_1$ be the interior of the triangle together with one vertex.  Let $X_2$ be the interior of the triangle together with another vertex.

Comment: Oh yeah! Indeed any the interior points of the edge with vertex $x_1$ and $x_2$ not lie in $X_1\cup X_2$, i.e. if $x_1$ is the vertex of $X_1$ and $x_2$ is the vertex of $X_2$ then $$x_1+t(x_2-x_2)\notin X_1\cup X_2$$ for any $t\in(0,1)$, right?